# Android Studio can not download SDK

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I have recently got a SSD and changed my Windows. But when I tried to install Android Studio, the wizard performed a quick install and downloaded nothing.
When I run the program it says "No Android SDK found". But the real problem is the next page (SDK components setup): the program detects an installed SDK that can't be checked or deleted, and there is a path that doesn't even exist.
[SDK components setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/il7L0.png)

I've tried to change the path to "C:\SDK", but whether I do it or not I will encounter 0 B total download size and the final page says "nothing to do!, Android SDK is up to date, SDK emulator directory is missing".

Clicking on "create new project" will show me this error: "Your Android SDK is missing, out of date or corrupted" with the "open SDK manager" button. SDK manager has no components on the list and clicking on "edit" will lead me to SDK components setup page again.
[Android SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79w7o.png)

Answer (score 3):

On android studio 4.2.1 I had the same problem but it was related to my region format and I changed it to English form Control Panel > Change date, time, or numbers formats
If region format wasn't your problem You might change your DNS Server and check your proxy settings